# Invalid syntax issue in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I am doing a lab and when I set a call to refer to another file, I get an invalid syntax issue. Can anyone help? Here it is:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> from tabulate import *
>>> from my_apic_em_functions import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    from my_apic_em_functions import *
  File "C:\Users\GARETT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\my_apic_em_functions.py", line 1
    Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also understand [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How do I attach this file?

Comment: Do not attach a file, rather, only a simplified code example of the trouble is all that is needed. Do not post images either, because no one can copy/paste your code to try.

Comment: Can anyone help?